# How to schedule local notifications with flutter

Tags: flutter, notifications, local

I'm unable to show a daily local notifications based on time picked by user.

To see if I forgot any permissions, I tried implementing a button to show a local notification straight away and that worked.

if a notification is scheduled, this code make sure it shows when the page loads

```
class _LocalNotificationWidgetState extends State<LocalNotificationWidget> {
  final notifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  Time timePickedtime;
  TimeOfDay _time = TimeOfDay.now();
  TimeOfDay picked;
  var timeText;
  bool showReminder;
  String remindTime;

 @override
  void initState() {
    getReminderTime().then((result) {
      setState(() {
        result != null ? timeText = result : timeText = '00:00';
      });
    });
    getReminder().then((result) {
      setState(() {
        showReminder = result;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

building the timepicker widget

```
   Widget _buildTimePicker() {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        await _showDailyAtTime(context);
      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
            color: Colors.white),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              timeText != null ? timeText.toString() : '00:00',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
            ),
            Switch(
              value: showReminder == null ? false : showReminder,
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                setState(() {
                  showReminder = value;
                  setReminder(value);
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

the scheduling method

```
Future<Null> _showDailyAtTime(BuildContext context) async {
    picked = await showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: _time);
    if (picked != null && picked != _time) {
      setState(() {
        _time = picked;
      });
    }
    if (picked != null) {
      timePickedtime = Time(picked.hour, picked.minute, 0);
    }

    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'repeatDailyAtTime channel id',
        'repeatDailyAtTime channel name',
        'repeatDailyAtTime description');
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    setState(() {
      timeText =
          '${_toTwoDigitString(picked.hour)}:${_toTwoDigitString(picked.minute)}';
      setReminderTime(timeText);
    });

    if (showReminder) {
      await notifications.showDailyAtTime(
          0,
          'Reminder',
          'Have you used this app today? Daily notification shown at approximately ${_toTwoDigitString(picked.hour)}:${_toTwoDigitString(picked.minute)}:',
          timePickedtime,
          platformChannelSpecifics);
    }
  }
```

storing schedule on device

```
  Future<bool> getReminder() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    return prefs.getBool('showReminder');
  }

  Future<bool> setReminder(bool value) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    return prefs.setBool('showReminder', value);
  }

  Future<bool> setReminderTime(String value) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    return prefs.setString('timeText', value);
  }

  Future<String> getReminderTime() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    return prefs.getString('timeText');
  }
```

Comment: Hi, if you found a solution, can you please share?

Comment: I set it up using InitState 
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
         AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/notifications_icon');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) plugin, the `zonedSchedule()` method can be used to set a scheduled notification relative to the device's time zone.

```dart
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
    0,
    'scheduled title',
    'scheduled body',
    tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
    const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'your channel id', 'your channel name',
            channelDescription: 'your channel description')),
    androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
    uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
        UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
```

Comment: To run it every day, you can use cron like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72869957/5527968

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution

SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
.then((value) async {
var initializationSettingsAndroid =
AndroidInitializationSettings('icon');

```
var initializationSettingsIOs = IOSInitializationSettings(
    requestAlertPermission: true,
    requestBadgePermission: true,
    requestSoundPermission: true,
    onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
        (int id, String tittle, String body, String payload) async {});
final MacOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsMacOS =
    MacOSInitializationSettings();
var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    iOS: initializationSettingsIOs,
    macOS: initializationSettingsMacOS);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
    onSelectNotification: (String payload) async {
  if (payload != null) {
    debugPrint('notification payload' + payload);
  }
});
```