# How to repeat local notification every day with dart-flutter? and how to parse '2:00 AM' time format To TimeZone?

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, date-format, datetime-parsing

I am trying to make a daily remainder to patient's medicine timings, I am using ***flutter_local_notifications*** and it works well.
this is my function i want to make it repeats daily,

```
void scheduleAlarm() async {
      var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'alarm_notif',
        'alarm_notif',
        'Channel for Alarm notification',
        icon: 'codex_logo',
        sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification_sound'),
        largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('drug'),
      );
      tz.initializeTimeZones();
      tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation('America/Detroit'));
      var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails(
          sound: 'notification_sound.wav',
          presentAlert: true,
          presentBadge: true,
          presentSound: true);
      var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
          android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
          iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        0,
        'Panadol',
        'Don\'t forget to take your medicine 2:00 AM',
        tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(Duration(seconds: 5)),
        platformChannelSpecifics,
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      );
    }
```

and I want to change this line so I could pass a string of timing that I got from TimePicker in this formate **'2:00 AM'**

```
tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(Duration(seconds: 5)),
```

Answer (score 0):

With your existing code, you can use the [cron](https://pub.dev/packages/cron) module like this to schedule an everyday notification.

```dart
cron.schedule(Schedule.parse('0 2 */1 * *'), () async {
      scheduleAlarm();
      print('Run scheduled notification');
});
```

Please note that your notification is delayed by 5 seconds, but note that `zonedSchedule()` need a future date too to be executed.

You can use [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru) to help you if you're not handy with cron expression.

**NOTE:** Cron need the app to be running to work.

Comment: Another way I can think of is to use the WorkManager and set the task to run once at a specific time like 10:00 AM on some date, which will set the periodic notification to show every week. The downside I can see is that it will miss the first schedule.